# how to Handle multiple users update a same record in web application (Spring mvc & DB oracle pl/sql)

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jsp, spring-mvc

how to Handle multiple users update a same record in web application (Spring mvc & DB oracle pl/sql) 
1) web application already live in production.
if I will use time stamp then I need to enhance the application more than 2000 existing UI page and DAOIMPL java file also
2) if I will use version then more than 4000 oracle table's to be alter and 
 adding one column as version & related jsp and java files also need to change

3) I can't store in session because same data reports uses multiple users. 
if I locked data unique id then multiple user same will not able to use.
Can any one help me how to handle enhancement in only one place then whole web application validation happen.

Example:
table name: Plastic_rope_bundle_stock

buckets_no  |  qty  |   product_type |   product_color| length

1001       |    100 kg |    soft     |  red           |1000 m

1002       |200 kg     |hard         | green          |200m

when some same type product comes A and B both users retrive the data in transaction page and try to update in same 
buckets (i.e 1001). how to Handle multiple users not allow update a same record in at same time  (save button) on transaction screen

Comment: Hi. Could you explain what result do you expect? If two different people change the same row. We should save in database first change? Second? or we should split row to two? Or may be we should lock row when some one try to update?

Comment: Well you shall change something! I recommend adding a field to all tables, but you can check all fields by something like `update table_name set x_field = newValue where id = :old_id and name = :old_name and x_field = :old_x_field and ....` but then you shall have old values of all fields which is harder than just a single version field.

Comment: @ Michael Piankov, result is 1st user to allow editing the data and send message to 2nd user data already changed. If two different people change the same row. We should save in database first change and message to 2nd user data already edited.

Comment: @ Amir Pashazadeh, thanks for your response.

Comment: @ Amir Pashazadeh, Thanks for your response.But there is not one table around 4 thousands tables in whole project for same problem.if will add new column then we will need to be add a new column around 4 thousand tables that consuming and need to change in JAVA and JSP files also.

Comment: @s mallick  how you solve the problem finally?

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible ways of handling such scenarios is through 'optimistic locking'. The name is bit of a misnomer, since it doesn't involve locking on record.

Here is an excellent read on this:
[concurrent editing without locking](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.in/2009/02/concurrent-editing-without-locking.html)